# Error: Importing Gurobi in Python/Spyder

Tags: python, gurobi

I installed Gurobi: 6.5.1 64bit
and Anaconda - Spyder 2.3.8; Python 2.7.11 64bit

When I try to import Gurobi:

```
from gurobipy import *
```

I get the error message:
"No module named gurobipy"

It is also not possible to install it via pip.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

cd to the folder where your gurobi program is held at the command line:

```
 cd gurobi460\win64
```

Then run the setup script at the command line:

```
python setup.py install
```